# Clang outputs error "no matching construct for initialization"

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, clang++

Compiling this code snippet with clang-425.0.27 ( based on LLVM3.2svn) :

```
class CStorage
{};

typedef boost::shared_ptr< CStorage >  AccessorPtr;

class CTest
{
public:
  CTest( const CStorage &rAccessor )
    : m_Accessor( rAccessor ){}
private:
  AccessorPtr m_Accessor;
};
```

**Getting compilation error:**

```
**error**: no matching constructor for initialization of 'AccessorPtr' (aka 'shared_ptr<CStorage>')
                        : m_Accessor( rAccessor ){}

**note**: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from
      'const FNPNS::TSM::CDirectBlockAccessor' to 'const boost::shared_ptr<FNPNS::TSM::CDirectBlockAccessor>' for 1st argument
template<class T> class shared_ptr
```

Comment: try `m_Accessor(new CStorage(rAccessor))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `boost::shared_ptr` constructor wants a pointer, you're passing it a reference. You might want to change your own constructor to take a pointer as well, or create a new `CStorage` object on the heap using the reference.

Comment: @Cplusplus11Dev: Then something is wrong in either GCC or Boost. But the code you posted *shouldn't work*.

Comment: looks like a bug in gcc compiler - clang spotted this error correctly in our framework where we have modified boost implementation to accommodate our business requirements.

Answer (score 1):

As @Joachim suggested your ctor expects a pointer.
 It might be better to pass a shared pointer (or a weak pointer, depending on your use case) which will keep the pointer in memory.